# SQL Flag Value for a Required Decimal

Tags: database, t-sql

In my Database I have a Required Decimal which can be in the range of

```
maxExclusive value="1000000000000000"
minExclusive value="-1000000000000000"
```

The User must enter a value in the front end and if they choose not to answer the question they can select N/A, the issue is that what is the best way to represent this value (N/A). the value cannot be NULL

Would representing the value outside the acceptable range be a good idea and just write additional logic to handle this use case. 
Ie. -9999999999999999

Comment: It seems that this use case is exactly why NULL exists -- is there a good reason you don't want to use it?

Answer (score 2):

I can think of three choices for representing an "out-of-range" value.

The first is the one you've rejected, which is to represent the value as NULL.

The second is the one you've proposed, which is to handle it as a special value and incorportate logic to handle the special value.

The third is to introduce a new flag, IsExclusiveValid, and to incorporate special logic using this flag instead.

In many cases, the second and third are about the same amount of work.  The third is ever so slightly more overhead in the database.  A more advanced version of the third case is to introduce your own type, but that is much more work.

Some people cringe at having special values.  But the different methods are pretty similar.